# Tiny dark border on title label of UIBUtton: what is it and how to remove it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

### Question

There is a tiny border on title label of `UIBUtton`, which is not there for `UILabels`.

```
[self.button setTitle:@"border" forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;

self.label.text = @"no borders!"
self.label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor] ;
```

Because of this border, `UIButton`s with light colors looks "dirty".

**What is it and how to remove it?**

---

### Pictures

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe those borders are drop shadows. Does `myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;` helps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are title text border shadows of `UIButton`.

By default it is looks like dark grey colour for button.

[image]

Click on **Shadow Color** and change it to **Clear Color**

[image]

You can done this by programatically also using this code:

```
 [self.button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
```

Comment: OK, it works fine. If I don't change the Shadow Color in IB but only in the code, it does not work. It seems that the setting in IB takes the control over the setting by code.

Comment: No that's not possible I have checked that, it also works with code too. Please check again, you have missed something.

Comment: I have double checked also. I mean if the button is created in IB but if I change the Shadow Color by code. The setting that is taken is the one in IB.

Comment: OK, I got it. The right code is `    [self setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;` not the one you give. This changes everything. Thanks for your help!!! You can update your answer.

Comment: Yes I have updated with that solution. It's working too. Thanks.